# Run Integration Test From Restarted App Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing

I would like to be able to write integration tests (not widget or unit) and have the app restart between each test so i can test the flow through the application.
Is this possible as Flutter's documentation does not appear to show this at all, or must I write individual 'setup' files (like app.dart in the example [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction)) for each end to end test I want?

If I do have to do this, how do I link it to only run the tests for a particular setup? Is it matched by name (e.g. app.dart links to app_test.dart so example.dart would link to example_test.dart) or by some other means?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://beltran.work/blog/restart-flutter-app-with-driver/) blog post talks exactly about what you are looking for. Hope this helps.